# Partially unpacking of tuple in Numpy array indexing

Tags: python, numpy

In order to solve a problem which is only possible element by element I need to combine NumPy's tuple indexing with an explicit slice.

```
def f(shape, n):
    """
    :param shape: any shape of an array
    :type shape: tuple
    :type n: int
    """
    x = numpy.zeros( (n,) + shape )
    for i in numpy.ndindex(shape):                   # i = (k, l, ...)
        x[:, k, l, ...] = numpy.random.random(n)
```

`x[:, *i]` results in a `SyntaxError` and `x[:, i]` is interpreted as `numpy.array([ x[:, k] for k in i ])`. Unfortunally it's not possible to have the n-dimension as last (`x = numpy.zeros(shape+(n,))` for `x[i] = numpy.random.random(n)`) because of the further usage of `x`.

EDIT: Here some example wished in comment.

```
>>> n, shape = 2, (3,4)
>>> x = np.arange(24).reshape((n,)+(3,4))
>>> print(x) 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
>>> i = (1,2)
>>> print(x[ ??? ])    # '???' expressed by i with any length is the question
array([ 6, 18])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a multi-dimensional numpy array and want to index it by combining a `:` slice with some number of other indices from a tuple `i`.

The index to the numpy array is a tuple, so you can basically just combine those 'partial' indices to one tuple and use that as the index. A naive approach might look like this

```
x[ (:,) + i ] = numpy.random.random(n) # does not work
```

but this will give a syntax error. Instead of `:`, you have to use the [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) builtin.

```
x[ (slice(None),) + i ] = numpy.random.random(n)
```